# HMVC Not Working Array Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on my home controller for my project I have a header and footer and home controller each with its own views.

In the header view I have in the head area `<title><?php echo $title;?></title>`

But I am trying to load title dynamically but hmvc does not seem to do that unless it is from the views.

View page content OK just not getting dynamic arrays working if have same array in another controller.

How do I make it work dynamically in the controller as not just the views?

**Home Controller.php**

```
<?php

class Home extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
    $this->load->module('catalog/common/header');
    $this->load->module('catalog/common/footer');   
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = array();
        $data['header'] = $this->header->index();
        $data['footer'] = $this->footer->index();

        $data['title'] = "This-Works"; // Need to work dynamically 
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
}
```

**Home View.php**

```
<?php echo $header;?>

Home

<?php echo $footer;?>
```

Header Controller

```
<?php

class Header extends MX_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('header');
    }
}
```

**Header View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title> // Not Working From Other Controllers.
</head>
<body>

Header
```

Comment: I hope you followed this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hmvc-an-introduction-and-application--net-11850

Comment: Not what I am after I know how to do logins and stuff. and load controller into view. but It's also says you can load module in controller but just not dynamic like in views.

Comment: Are you trying to only set the title variable in one place? I'm a little confused. If the title will not change, just set it as a constant or config item.

Comment: Each main controller has it's own title. In hmvc to make it dynamic it seems you can only load module in to view to make it dynamic. It should be the other way round. I prefer to have module dynamic in controller.